# Uniform convergence of $\sum^\infty _{n=1} {x e^{-nx}\cos(nx)}$

Tags: analysis

How can i prove uniform convergence on $E=[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ ?
$$\sum^\infty _{n=1} {x e^{-nx}\cos(nx)}$$

Comment: Please share your thoughts and efforts.

Comment: I tried to use Dirichlet test for uniform convergence. $u_n(x) = xe^{-nx}$, $v_n(x) = \cos(nx)$.
I dont know how to prove that $\sum^k_{n=1}{\cos(nx)}$ is bounded for any $x \in E$.
$|\cos(x) + \cos(2x) + ... + \cos(nx)| <= \frac{1}{|sin(\frac{x}{2})|}$
But if $x$ is near to $0$, than $\frac{1}{|sin(\frac{x}{2})|}$ is very big, so i cant prove that this value is bounded.

Comment: Why do you think it converges uniformly there? I would guess it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried the Weierstrass M test?

Comment: $M-$ test doesn’t work here. You obviously can’t find an upper-bound of the absolute value due to $e^{-nx}x$.

Comment: Define $f_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N xe^{-nx}\cos(nx)$ and note that $f_N(1/N) = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{N} e^{-n/N}\cos(n/N)$ is a Riemann sum. Compare $\lim_{N\to \infty}f_N(1/N)$ to $\lim_{N\to\infty}f_N(0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For $N$ even, let

$$T_N(x)=\sum_{n=N/2}^{N}xe^{-nx}\cos (nx).$$

If the convergence is uniform, then $T_N\to 0$ uniformly. Consider $T_N(1/N).$

Comment: should be $$cos (nx).$$ instead of $$cos (Nx).$$ ?

Comment: @NPE Yes indeed, thank you.

Comment: so the convergence is non-uniform, right? By the way, is the series even pointwise convergent? And, The test you display is Cauchy-Criterion right?

Comment: @vidyarthi the answers are yes, yes, and on the last one I would say it shows CC does not hold..  For  pointwise convergence: $x=0$ is obvious,if  $x>0$ the terms in absolute value are bounded above by $xe^{-nx}.$